# Parsing XML file with xmlns tag defined but not using namespaces

Tags: c#, xml, xml-parsing, xml-namespaces

I am struggling with parsing `XPathDocument` with `XPathNavigator` where XML document contains `xmlns` tag, but no namesapce prefix is used.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Order version="1" xmlns="http://example.com">
    <Data>
        <Id>1</Id>
        <b>Aaa</b>
    </Data>
</Order>
```

`SelectSingleNode` method requires namespace manager with namespace defined.

```
XmlNamespaceManager nsmgr = new XmlNamespaceManager(nav.NameTable);
nsmgr.AddNamespace("ns","http://example.com");
```

As a result I have to start using `ns` prefix in all XPath expressions, although the original XML file does not use prefixes, for e.g.:

```
nav.SelectSingleNode("/ns:Order/ns:Data/ns:Id", nsmgr)
```

This adds an unnecessary complexity.

Is there any way to push `XPathNavigator` to ignore namespace and its prefixes? Ot at least use of prefixes, as namespace definition itself exists only once, so not much effort

Comment: I couldn't agree more, the only way that I've found is to match on localname(), which is just as ugly as prefixing every element with a namespace.  Apparently in Saxon XPath v3, name spaces are only matched if you specify them, by default things match on localname().  I wish they thought of that in XPath 1.0, which sadly in the Microsoft C# world we are stuck with, unless you use Saxon or similar.

Answer (score 0):

The XML has a default namespace. So each and every XML element is bound to it, visible or not.

It is better to use **LINQ to XML**.

It is a preferred XML API, and available in the .Net Framework since 2007.

**c#**

```
void Main()
{
    XDocument xdoc = XDocument.Parse(@"<Order version='1' xmlns='http://example.com'>
            <Data>
                <Id>1</Id>
                <b>Aaa</b>
            </Data>
        </Order>");

    XNamespace ns = xdoc.Root.GetDefaultNamespace();

    foreach (XElement elem in xdoc.Descendants(ns + "Data"))
    {
        Console.WriteLine("ID: {0}, b: {1}"
            , elem.Element(ns + "Id")?.Value
            , elem.Element(ns + "b")?.Value);
    }
}
```